# What is the best wifi adaptor available that's compatible with Kali Linux?

Tags: networking, usb, wireless, linux

I've got Kali Linux up, but I'm thinking I don't have a compatible card. What is the most optimal setup regarding range, etc?

What troubleshooting steps can I take to fix my incompatibility issues if any?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118946/what-is-the-most-optimal-wifi-adapter-compatible-with-kali-linux

Answer (score 1):

There is no WiFi adapter that is compatible with specific distro, as all Linux distros use very similar Kernel.

I've tried many cheap adapters from eBay and all are working without problems on RPI.